# Syntastic avoid irrelevant errors

Tags: vim, syntastic

I've recently installed the `syntastic` plugin in my vim installation. However I'm getting annoyed by irrelevant errors reported by syntastic.

I installed in order to make it work `code sniffer` and `phpmd`.

How can I tell syntastic to stop giving me such irrelevant errors like:

`Missing file doc comment`

or

`Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 8 spaces, found 4`

I'd like to get only real errors like `missing a semicolon;`

Comment: I believe you have to figure out which of the syntax checkers are producing the 'noise', and see if you're able to change its arguments to not display certain warnings or errors. https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/PHP:---phpcs http://phpmd.org/documentation/index.html

Comment: Mmm googling I've found that these messages are thrown by PHPCS (code sniffer), but I've got still no idea how to tell syntastic to skip phpcs, I tried adding `let g:syntastic_phpcs_disable = 1`in my vimrc but nothing changed.

Comment: See `:h syntastic-filetype-checkers`, .e.g `let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ["php", "phpmd"]` if you dont want `phpcs`. I'm not sure how to disable certain aspects of specific checkers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments, you can define which syntax checkers to use with the `g:syntastic_<filetype>_checkers = []` variable.

In this case, you might want something like this to disable code sniffer (`phpcs`):

```
let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ["php", "phpmd"]
```

For more information see `:h syntastic-filetype-checkers`.